# Java epoch time on server converted to client time

Tags: java, date, calendar, timezone, epoch

A server is storing the date/time of a client action with System.currentTimeMillis(). Let's say this server is in the EST time zone.

A client in France wants to see what time that action was made. That long value stored via System.currentTimeMillis() (on the US server) is returned to the client in France.

I'm having problems understanding how to make that conversion on the client side to accurately describe their action time. My understanding is that on the server the System.currentTimeMillis() is a zoneless UTC time. Things seem strange when I instantiate a Calendar object with a "UTC" timezone, so is the server storing a time zoned epoch time when it saves with currentTimeMillis()

First attempt:

```
    String timezone = clientTimezone;//Lets say france

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(time); //This time var is the server stored value (currentTimeMillis)
    
    if(!timezone.equals("")) {
        long timezoneAlteredTime = time + TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone).getRawOffset();
        cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone));
        cal.setTimeInMillis(timezoneAlteredTime);
    }
```

Other attempt:

```
    String timezone = clientTimezone;//Lets say france
    TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(utc);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(time); //This time var is the server stored value 
    
    if(!timezone.equals("")) {
        long timezoneAlteredTime = time + TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone).getRawOffset();
        cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone));
        cal.setTimeInMillis(timezoneAlteredTime);
    }
```

Am I misinterpreting this issue altogether? How would you go about this conversion

Comment: You shouldn’t make any conversion. The count of milliseconds since the epoch, as from `System.currentTimeMillis()`, is the same everywhere in the world and independent of time zone. Because the eopch is one point in time, the same point in time in all time zones (and not the same clock time of day).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar` and `TimeZone`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `ZoneId`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3):

The [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65256180/642706) is correct: Call `Instant::atZone` to adjust a moment from UTC to a particular time zone. Same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

Here are a few more thoughts.

> Let's say this server is in the EST time zone.

FYI, generally best to set UTC as the time zone on servers.

> the System.currentTimeMillis() is a zoneless UTC time

Not zoneless. That method returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch reference of the first moment of 1970 as seen in [UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). (An [offset-from-UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero hours-minutes-seconds)

Without the context of an offset-from-UTC or a time zone, you cannot represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

> Things seem strange when I instantiate a Calendar object

Everything about the `Calendar` class is strange.

That is why we stopped using that terrible class years ago. Use only the *java.time* classes.

> A server is storing the date/time of a client action with System.currentTimeMillis().

We have a class for that: [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). So no need to use a mere integer number, now you can use a type-safe and handy class.

The `Instant` class represents a moment as seen in UTC. Its objects use a resolution of nanoseconds, though most computer clocks nowadays can capture a moment as microseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

You can convert between your count-of-milliseconds and `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( yourCountOfMillis ) ;
```

An `Instant` is in UTC, by definition. To see the same moment from an on other offset, use `OffsetDateTime`. To see the same moment in a particular time zone, use `ZonedDateTime`.

Understand that a time zone is a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. Politicians frequently change the offset of their jurisdiction(s) for various reasons.

Search Stack Overflow to learn more. These issues have been covered many many times already.

Comment: *Everything about the `Calendar` class is strange.* So well said.

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

This is pretty straightforward when you know how. And I recommend that you leave the work to java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

```
    String clientTimezone = "Europe/Paris";
    long time = 1_607_708_578_154L;
    
    ZonedDateTime timeInClientTimeZone = Instant.ofEpochMilli(time)
            .atZone(ZoneId.of(clientTimezone));
    
    System.out.println(timeInClientTimeZone);
```

Output from this example code snippet is:

> 2020-12-11T18:42:58.154+01:00[Europe/Paris]

### What went wrong in your code?

> My understanding is that on the server the System.currentTimeMillis()
> is a zoneless UTC time.

This far your understanding is correct.

Even though the epoch is usually defined in UTC, the clue here is *zoneless*. So you don’t need any date-time object in UTC. You also don’t need to make any adjustments to the millisecond count, so by doing so, you are turning a correct time into an incorrect one.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.